Django URL reset after authentication fail
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)  
        return redirect('home')  
    else:
        error_message = "Invalid username or password."
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'error_message': error_message})

Using the above code, if user enters wrong credentials, login.html shows up successfully with error message.
But now the URL is http://localhost:8000/authentication_view/.
Now if the user re-enters credentials, the URL will be
http://localhost:8000/authentication_view/authentication_view/,
and it creates Page Not Found error.
If I use return redirect('login_view'), then the error message will not show.

Could someone help me how to show login page with error message without adding Authentication View to the URL?
I was expecting: if user provides wrong credentials, he gets error message and goes back to login page. Now he can re-enter credentials. But now login page is not usable because authentication view name is already added to the URL. New login attempt will add authentication view name twice the URL.

Share that full view, the URLconf and the template; (specifically the form).

The issue with the action mentioned in the html page in form tag.
you must have something like <form method="post" action="authentication_view/">
To solve the issue, best way is to remove the action from form tag. by default html form submit to same page. do something like this.
<form method="post">

If you are loading page from different url and submitting form to other mention the complete url. in your case it should be.
<form method="post" action="/authentication_view">


Thank you Vinay Vishwakarma. Problem solved after moving "/" from the end to the begining (  ). in URLs file, I had to remove "/" as well. path('authentication_view', views.authentication_view, name='authentication_view'),

Show us the html code for the login page
The error could be from the action attribute in the login form
Better use dynamic links as in :
action = {% url 'login_view' %} or the name U gave the view in the urls.py.

Your answer does not completely answer the question. Requests for clarification should be made as comments -- you will gain permission to comment once you have a little reputation.
